# Struggling to set up nativebase in a React Expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I have tried so many different ways to set nativebase up with expo and am still having an issue. At the moment I'm using the
[Getting Started documentation](https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html) found on the nativebase website.

I first create a new app with expo using

> expo init myapp

Then I install nativebase using

> npm install native-base --save

Then I finally install the font

> expo install expo-font

I even copy the App.js found in the getting started documentation, and after I start the app and try to run it on an emulator I face the below error

**Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons/Fontisto" from "node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\IconNB.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.**

What am I missing? Coming from .NET world this whole process with dependencies is so painful...

*Edit 1

I'm sure someone will make mention of the fact that the error message mentions @expo/vector-icons and I have not installed that. When running before I install this package I get that error, and after I install the mentioned package I still face the exact same error.

Comment: In the mean time, use version 2.13.8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try with this version of native base :

```
npm i --save-exact native-base@2.13.8
```

Expo should release a version with that version .

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've been just starting out with react-native. Is this a common issue where different versions of packages have issues with others, and if so, is there a efficient way of narrowing it down?

Comment: You just saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can run the below command with Expo

`npm i --save-exact native-base@2.13.8`

Still this version is not available, but its working, really don't know why?